# In RabbitMQ, how can I tell if an existing Classic Queue is v1 or v2?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there any way to determine if an existing Classic Queue is v1 vs. v2?

Unless I'm doing something wrong, the Managment UI does not appear to differentiate between v1 and v2. Am I missing something in the Management UI? If not, is there any other way to determine the version of an existing classic queue?